# Basic Object Oriented subfunction definition and use in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

Sorry to bother the community for this but I have unfortunately to code in Perl :'(. It is about an OO perl code I want to understand but I am failing to put all the pieces together.

The following is a template of code that represents somehow what I am currently looking at. The following is the class **MyClass**:

```
package Namespace::MyClass;
sub new($)
{
    my ($class) = @_;
    $self = { };
    bless ($self, $class);
}

sub init($$)
{
    my ($self, $param1) = @_;
    $self->{whatever} = ($param1, $param1, $param1);
}
```

and then the following is a **script.pl** that supposedly uses the class:

```
#!/path/to/your/perl

require Namespace::MyClass;

my myClass = new Namespace::MyClass()

myClass->init("data_for_param1");
```

There may be error but I am interested more in having the following questions answered than having my possibly wrong code corrected:

- Questions group 1 : "$" in a sub definition means I need to supply one parameter, right? If so, why does new ask for one and I do not supply it? Has this to do with the call in the script using () or something similar to how Python works (self is implied)?
- Question group 2 : is for the same previous reason that the **init** subroutine (here a method) declares to expect two parameters? If so, is the blessing in some way implying a self is ever passed for all the function in the module?

I ask this because I saw that in non blessed modules one $ = one parameter.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is maybe because **new** is a function like any other and Namespace::MyClass() is sort of "give me the reference of MyClass" and bless will make something out of it? Could I have written new(\Namespace::MyClass) or something ?

Comment: Don't use prototypes in OO perl code.  From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes: `Method calls are not influenced by prototypes either, because the function to be called is indeterminate at compile time, since the exact code called depends on inheritance.`

Comment: @tjd Better advice for a beginner might be "Don't use prototypes in *any* Perl code."

Comment: feeling it is unfortunate that you have to code in Perl is understandable if it isn't your thing, but expressing that is maybe not the best way to start a question to people who presumably like Perl

Comment: Yes, I apologize ysth. It just gives me the idea Perl is not meant for huge project but for something like improved scripting or prototyping and it already made me cry blood multiple times :) although I am all bash, *nix, awk, sed, vim & friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### QG1:

Prototypes (like "$") mean *exactly nothing* in Method calls.

> [Method calls are not influenced by prototypes either, because the function to be called is indeterminate at compile time, since the exact code called depends on inheritance.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Most experienced Perl folk avoid prototypes entirely unless they are trying to imitate a built-in function.  Some [PHBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) inexperienced in Perl mandate their use under the mistaken idea that they work like prototypes in other languages.

The 1st parameter of a Method call is the Object (Blessed Ref) or Class Name (String) that called the Method.  In the case of your `new` Method that would be 'Namespace::MyClass'.

Word to the wise:  [Also avoid indirect Method calls.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods)  Rewrite your line using the direct Method call as follows: `my $myClass = Namespace::MyClass->new;`

### QG2:

Your `init` method is getting `$myClass` as it's 1st parameter because it is what 'called' the method.  The 2nd parameter is from the parameter list.  Blessing binds the name of the Class to the Reference, so that when a method call is seen, It knows which class in which to start the search for the correct `sub`.  If the correct `sub` is not immediately found, the search continues in the classes named in the class's `@ISA` array.

Comment: also, even if these weren't method calls, the prototypes would have had no effect because when the calls were compiled, the class wouldn't have been loaded yet (because of using `require` instead of `use`)

Comment: BTW, the [perobj](perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) uses the 
my $myClass = Namespace::Myclass->new(); convention.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use prototypes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966)! They don't do what you think they do.

Prototypes in Perl are mainly used to allow functions to be defined without the use of parentheses or to allow for functions that take array references to use the array name like `pop` or `push` do. Otherwise, prototypes can cause more trouble and heartbreak than experienced by most soap opera characters.

Comment: Parentheses are optional even if you don't use prototypes: `perl -wE 'sub foo { say "bar" } foo'` Just one more reason not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

is what you actually want to do validate parameters? if so then that is not the purpose of prototypes. you could try using [signatures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures), but for some reason they are new and still experimental. some consider lack of a stable signatures feature to be a flaw of perl. the alternatives are CPAN and writing code in your subs/methods that explicitly validate the params.

Comment: For `signatures`, those using Perl versions prior to 5.20 need not apply.  CPAN is probably the way to go at this time.